# angular - Remove module at build time

Tags: angular, angular-builder

I have a module (Let's say data-generator) which is used only in dev mode (`npm start`).

We don't require that while deploying it (in `npm run build`).

Is there any way to do that? The following path `generate-data` neither required to be in PROD build nor while building app.

Router entry

[image: sample code]

Comment: Where is this executed?

Comment: This is router entry

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition to not load this route based on the environment variable prod. It should do the trick. Something like:

```
environment.production ? 
  {
    path: 'home',
    canActivate: [HomeGuard],
    data: {
      roles: config.accessRoles.home,
    },
    component: HomeComponent,
  } : {},
```